# react-hook-form submit does not pick up changeText from jest test

Tags: jestjs, react-hook-form

I have the following `react-native-form`:

```js
const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, errors } = useForm();

const onSubmit = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    .then((info) => {
      console.log(info.additionalUserInfo.profile);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};

  <View>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Email"
      testID="email-input"
      onChangeText={(t) => setValue("email", t)}
      style={styles.loginTextInput}
    ></TextInput>
    <TextInput
      secureTextEntry={true}
      testID="password-input"
      placeholder="Password (min. 8 characters)"
      onChangeText={(t) => setValue("password", t)}
      style={styles.loginTextInput}
    ></TextInput>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      testID={"login-email-button"}
      style={[styles.loginButton, styles.loginEmailButton]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login with Email</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

I am testing the submission and the call to `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` using `jest` in the following test:

```js
test("submit works", async () => {
  const { getByPlaceholderText, getByTestId, getByText } = render(
    <EmailLogin />
  );
  const emailInput = getByTestId("email-input");
  const passwordInput = getByTestId("password-input");
  const submitButton = getByTestId("login-email-button");

  const email = "foo@email.com";
  const password = "password";
  fireEvent.changeText(emailInput, email);
  fireEvent.changeText(passwordInput, password);
  fireEvent.press(submitButton);

  expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    email,
    password
  );
});
```

where I've mocked out `signInWithEmailAndPassword` as a `jest.fn()`.

When I run this test, it fails with:

```js
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "foo@email.com", "password"
Received: undefined, undefined
```

And I noticed the `console.log(data)` I have in my `onSubmit` function prints out:

```js
console.log
  {}
```

which means no text was picked up.

How do I go about testing this form?

Comment: Are you using enzyme as well? it'll be a lot easier with it

Comment: Can you show how you are mocking the `firebase` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why it returns undefined for you is that you are trying to test asynchronous behaviour in a sync way. I would suggest using `Promises` in your `onSubmit` method to wait for the `firebase auth` call to finish.

Something like this could work

```js
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  return await firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    .then((info) => {
      console.log(info.additionalUserInfo.profile);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

This would then ensure that you are waiting for the sign in to happen.

In your test, I would mock the firebase to something like this

```js
jest.mock('firebase', () => ({
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(),
   })
);
```

And then in your test, you would also need to use `waitFor()` to wait for the sign in to happen so then you can check your results. Something like this could work

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    email,
    password
  ););
```

I haven't tested it myself but try the idea of using async and Promises and let me know if that works.